# how to save the final box at the end of tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Perhaps the question is unclear. I know how to put a tikzpicture inside a box. I made it in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz) like this

```
\newsavebox{\mycandle}
\savebox{\mycandle}{% 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.1]
   ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```

But in this case I put a box (`\pgfpic`perhaps it's the final box) into a box and I would like to know if it's possible to save the final box when `\endtikzpicture` arrives.

I'm not sure but I think the good box is `\pgfpic`. In the file  `pgfcorescopes.code.tex` and at the end of the macro `\endpgfpicture`, I found `\pgfsys@endpicture`  and then `\pgfsys@typesetpicturebox\pgfpic`. Th first seems to depend of the driver and I don't understand the code and for the second macro `\pgfsys@typesetpicturebox` the  definition is inside  the file pgfsys.code.tex

Here the code of this macro :

```
\def\pgfsys@typesetpicturebox#1{%
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@shift@baseline\relax%
  \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@picminy\relax%
  %
  %
  \advance\pgf@picmaxy by-\pgf@picminy\relax% maxy is now the height
  \advance\pgf@picmaxx by-\pgf@picminx\relax% maxx is now the width
  \setbox#1=\hbox{\hskip-\pgf@picminx\lower\pgf@picminy\box#1}%
  \ht#1=\pgf@picmaxy%
  \wd#1=\pgf@picmaxx%
  \dp#1=0pt%
  \leavevmode%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@trimleft@final\relax  \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt \else\kern\pgf@xa\fi
  \raise-\pgf@ya\box#1%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@trimright@final\relax \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt \else\kern\pgf@xa\fi
}
```

But I don't understand the comment about this macro :

> ```
> % Called after a picture has been typeset in box #1. This
> % command should insert the box into the normal TeX code. The box #1
> % will still be a ``raw'' box that contains only the \special's. The
> % job of this command is to resize and shift this box according to the
> % baseline shift and the size of the box.
> %
> % This command has a default implementation.
> ```

Well I'm lost in all these codes and I'm not sure if what I want is possible. Perhaps it's a bad idea.

Comment: The code of the `spy` library has a box `\copy` application which may be inspiring for you.

Comment: Interesting and fine idea ! I need to give a look at this code but at first glance, the code is short but  ... without comments.

Comment: Yes, it's a little bit difficult to make your way around it but the general idea is to use the box content in the `path picture` option. If you look at the manual for `path picture` it's a little bit easier to understand the motivation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I say

```
\newsavebox{\mycandle}
\savebox{\mycandle}{% 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.1]
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}}
```

then the log from `\showbox\mycandle` (with high values of `\showboxbreadth` and `\showboxdepth`) is

```
> \box36=
\hbox(3.24544+0.0)x3.24544
.\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
.\hbox(3.24544+0.0)x3.24544
..\glue 0.2
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted -0.2
...\pdfliteral{q }
...\pdfliteral{0 G }
...\pdfliteral{0 g }
...\pdfliteral{0.3985 w }
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\pdfliteral{q }
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\pdfliteral{0.0 0.0 m }
....\pdfliteral{2.83484 2.83484 l }
....\pdfliteral{S }
....\pdfliteral{Q }
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
...\pdfliteral{n }
...\pdfliteral{Q }
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
```

So you've *not* the final box, which is surrounded by suitable `\pdfcolorstack` instruction (in `pdflatex`). They become `\special{color push gray 0}` and `\special{color pop}` with `latex` or `xelatex`. I don't think it's really safe trying to get the inner box before those paired commands are issued.

Comment: Finally "The box #1 will still be a ``raw'' box that contains only the \special's." is the problem ?  I think you are right when you say "it's not really safe trying ...". So it was a bad idea!