# Redefining macro with arguments in a macro with arguments

Tags: macros, programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (##1) in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument)

In the following code, I would like to build one macro `\caseWord` with two arguments corresponding to `Case` and `end case` so as to change the macro `\algocf@Case` which have two arguments. How can I achieve this ?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[longend]{algorithm2e}

    \makeatletter
        \renewcommand\algocf@Case[2]{%
            \KwSty{Case} #1 \algocf@block{#2}{%
                \@algocf@endoption{end case}%
            }%
        }
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \Begin{
        \Switch{X}{
            \Case{1}{
                \While{Continue}{Action}
            }
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This must be a duplicate of something:-) You need to use `##1` and `##2`

Comment: There are further examples of doubling up `#` here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79151/1090

Comment: If someone want to destroy my question. Just do it... Sorry for this duplicate. :-(

Comment: There should be a (more sensible than my tree example) canonical question/answer for the need to double `#` it is probably more useful to close this as duplicate rather than just delete it. I'm just looking for a good question to reference...

Comment: Good choice for the duplicated questions !