# Christmas theme

Tags: themes, fun

In the process of making a paper for school look good, I came to wonder, if there was such a thing as latex themes for regular papers? What I am think about in particular would be a Christmas theme, such that there would be Christmas trees, lights and Christmas stuff around the content of the actually text?

Comment: Sorry for my comment, but is this something to be done with TeX? It's better to use graphics softwares to do this, like Inkscape, for example.

Comment: One could definitely argue that. This was more a wondering question, as I have not be able to find the answer through google.

Comment: When you talked about [Christmas trees](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/christmas-tree-3/), one has been made with tikz with snowflakes and stuff.
Of course, you would need a lot of other stuff, but it is a start.

Comment: When @TKO linked to the christmas tree in texample.net I want to point to to original place of this: [How can we draw a Christmas tree with decorations, using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz).

Comment: And as Gonzalo linked to an image on vector.net: https://www.google.com/#q=intitle:christmas+site%3Avector.net&oq=intitle:christmas+site%3Avector.net Pay attention to the licenses!

Comment: @Sigur I think this is the wrong place to argue against using LaTeX (and the upvotes suggest I am not alone in my thinking).

Comment: @Vivi, sorry. My fault.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One possibility would be to get a nice image and use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{christmas.pdf}}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{.2}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another option using a not so distracting decoration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=\paperheight]{ejemplo}}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{.4}
\SetBgPosition{current page.west}
\SetBgHshift{2cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The images were taken from [`here`](http://www.vector.net/2009/christmas-tree-vectors/) and they are licensed as "Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License", so I think there's no legal issues using them here; otherwise, please let me know and I'll change them.

Comment: That does look quite nice, but it's a little to distracting from the content. What I was looking was decorations around the content :)

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk Same idea; get a nice image with a christmas theme frame and use the package to place it at the frame.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by placing it at the frame?

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk something like a decorative border, like the one in the second example code in my updated answer.

Comment: I just tried it out, and that worked beautifully! I'll use that for my next assignment :) thank you :) I am, however, still interested in knowing if it could be done with Tex?

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk sure; you can use, for example, `tikz` to create the design you want, and then use the `background` package to place the design in the desired position, with the desired attributes. Or do you mean using Plain TeX instead of LaTeX?

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk I appreciate you accepting my answer, but perhaps it is so soon? Perhaps you will get some other answers offering a better alternative? :-)

Comment: The image link is broken. Any chance you could post the image here or link it again?

Answer (score 19):

Here's an example that puts stars and snowflakes around the body of the text. You can adapt the code to add baubles, trees, angels etc as required.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\newcommand{\snowflake}{\resizebox{2cm}{!}{\ding{102}}}

\newcommand{\myfancyframe}[1]{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(n.base),
    decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=star,shape size=10pt,
    shape sep=1cm},
     star points=8]%
  \node[draw,decorate,fill=yellow,inner sep=5mm] (n) {#1};
  \path (n.north east) ++(1cm,1cm) node {\snowflake};
  \path (n.north west) ++(-1cm,1cm) node {\snowflake};
  \path (n.south west) ++(-1cm,-1cm) node {\snowflake};
  \path (n.south east) ++(1cm,-1cm) node {\snowflake};
  \useasboundingbox (n.north west) rectangle (n.south east);
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\onecolumn

\setflowframe{1}{border=myfancyframe,offset=-2.6cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

This sets up one frame the size of the typeblock (via `\onecolumn`). Since there's only one frame, I haven't bothered assigning a label to it, so I've just referenced it by its number (`1`) when setting the frame attributes (via `\setflowframe`). The command `\myfancyframe` puts stars and snowflakes around its argument. (I adapted the example given at the end of [Framed Boxes](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/fbox.html).) This can then be used as a border for the frame. The border is set using the `border` key with the name of the command *without* the leading backslash. (See chapter 3 of the [flowfram user guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram/ffuserguide.pdf).) The offset compensates for the thick border that shifts the frame out of whack. This value will need changing if you modify `\myfancyframe`. (If you use the `flowfram` package's `draft` option, you can see the outline of where the frame contents are expected.)

[image: Resulting page]