# How to draw a tree?

Tags: pstricks, trees

How to draw a  tree like

[image]

using LaTeX and how can I give the labelling to the vertices and the edges?

Comment: related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/policy-on-how-do-i-draw-this-questions

Comment: Use e.g. [`pst-tree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-tree).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any _specific problems_ you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I don't suppose one of these answers would help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz

Comment: -1: “This question does not show any research effort”

Comment: @Senthil.G: At least make an effort to give the question a meaningful title so people with a similar problem have a chance of finding this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\begin{document}

\small\psset{radius=3pt,treesep=6mm}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2.75)(13,3)
\psline(12,0)
\psforeach{\iA}{0,1,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12}{\uput[90](\iA,0){\iA}}
\psforeach{\iA}{2,8}{\uput[-90](\iA,0){\iA}}
\rput[t](0,3pt){%
  \pstree[radius=3pt,tnpos=b,tnsep=0pt]{\Tc*{3pt}}{%
    \TC*~{30}~[tnpos=a,tnsep=-15pt]{15}
    \TC*~{42}~[tnpos=a,tnsep=-15pt]{21}
    \TC*~{56}~[tnpos=a,tnsep=-15pt]{28}
    \TC*~{72}~[tnpos=a,tnsep=-15pt]{36}}}
\rput[b](2,-3pt){%
  \pstree[treemode=U,tnpos=a,tnsep=0pt]{\Tc*{3pt}}{%
    \TC*~{88}~[tnpos=b,tnsep=-15pt]{45}
    \TC*~{108}~[tnpos=b,tnsep=-15pt]{55}
    \TC*~{130}~[tnpos=b,tnsep=-15pt]{66}
    \TC*~{154}~[tnpos=b,tnsep=-15pt]{78}}}
\rput[t](4,3pt){%
  \pstree[radius=3pt,tnpos=b,tnsep=0pt]{\Tc*{3pt}}{%
    \TC*~{178}~[tnpos=a,tnsep=-15pt]{91}
    \TC*~{206}~[tnpos=a,tnsep=-15pt]{105}
    \TC*~{236}~[tnpos=a,tnsep=-15pt]{120}
    \TC*~{268}~[tnpos=a,tnsep=-15pt]{136}}}
% ...
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

With TikZ, for the fun of doing it in one path (just a start):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={
  level distance=2cm, sibling distance=1cm
  },
  point/.style={circle,
    fill,
    inner sep=1.4pt
  },
  every label/.style={font=\scriptsize}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw (0,0)
 node[point,label={north:0}]{}
  child{edge from parent node[label={west:15}]{}; \node[point,label={south:30}]{}}
  child{edge from parent node[label={west:21}]{}; \node[point,label={south:42}]{}}
  child{edge from parent node[label={east:28}]{}; \node[point,label={south:56}]{}}
  child{edge from parent node[label={east:36}]{}; \node[point,label={south:72}]{}}
--node[above,midway,label={above:1}]{}(3,0)
node[point,label={south:2}] {}[grow'=up]
  child{edge from parent node[label={west:45}]{}; \node[point,label={north:88}]{}}
  child{edge from parent node[label={west:55}]{}; \node[point,label={north:108}]{}}
  child{edge from parent node[label={east:66}]{}; \node[point,label={north:130}]{}}
  child{edge from parent node[label={east:78}]{}; \node[point,label={north:154}]{}}
--node[above,midway,label={above:3}]{}(6,0)
node[point,label={north:4}] {} [grow'=down]
  child{edge from parent node[label={west:..}]{}; \node[point,label={south:..}]{}}
  child{edge from parent node[label={west:..}]{}; \node[point,label={south:..}]{}}
  child{edge from parent node[label={east:..}]{}; \node[point,label={south:..}]{}}
  child{edge from parent node[label={east:..}]{}; \node[point,label={south:..}]{}}  
  ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]