# Figure grid with different dimensions

Tags: tables, floats

My question is very similar to this one: [Sub-figures of different sizes grid layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286737/sub-figures-of-different-sizes-grid-layout)

However, I can't use the `subcaption` package (I am using `subfigure`) and I also do not want them to have captions, so if I can avoid using `subfigure` at all maybe it would be better?

This is the output that I need:

[image]

I tried using the code from [this answer by Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286739/271037) but I could not get it to work.

```latex
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth,height=1.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        \smallskip
        \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \end{tabular}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Cats}
\end{figure}
```

Do note that this code is only for the first two columns, I have not yet tried to add the last one.

**Edit:** My current attempt is the following (the tabular lines are just for reference):

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-a}} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-b} &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-c}}
    \\ \hline
    & \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-c} & \\
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

**Edit 2:** Using [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661091/271037) and changing each width is making the images very small:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tblr}[t]{colspec={*{3}{X[c,m]}},
                cell{1}{1,3} = {r=2}{ }
                }
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-b}
        &   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-c} \\
    &   \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-b}
        &   \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Cats}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: And what is now the problem?

Comment: @Zarko In my solution using `multirow`, the dimensions are correct but the last column is misaligned vertically. In the solution adapted from your answer, the images are all too small, as they do not occupy the whole space (`0.4\linewidth`, `0.15\linewidth`, and `0.3\linewidth`).

Comment: I still guessing what you after. Your use of my code is wrong. See edit of ma answer,

Comment: @Zarko it was exactly that, I am not familiar with the `tabularray` package. Thank you.

Comment: `tabularray` package is very powerful and it is worth to make yourself more familiar with it. It has good,  concise documentation with a lot of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tblr}[t]{colspec={*{3}{X[c,m]}},
                cell{1}{1,3} = {r=2}{ } % <--- define multirow cells
                }
\includegraphics[height=1.5\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-b}
        &   \includegraphics[height=1.5\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-c} \\
    &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-b}
        &   \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Cats}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
From edited question, where you change desired appearance of images, now I guess, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tblr}[t]{colspec={Q[c,m, wd=0.3\linewidth] 
                         Q[c,m, wd=0.25\linewidth]
                         Q[c,m, wd=0.4\linewidth] },
                cell{1}{1,3} = {r=2}{ } % <--- define multirow cells
                }
\includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-b}
        &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-c} \\
    &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-b}
        &   \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Cats}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I got a `LaTeX error: File 'tabulararray.sty' not found`. Is it possible to do this with `multirow` instead? I have been trying but everything is misaligned vertically.

Comment: Just instal this package!

Comment: Seems like I just imported it wrongly, it works. Could you explain why the `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}` is necessary? Also, can I specify the proportions based on width? I want `0.3\linewidth` for the first column, `0.15\linewidth` for the middle column, and `0.4\linewidth` for the last one.

Comment: All, what you now explain in comment, is not present in question. I show you a skeleton, how you can solve your šproblem, in it you can change options as you wish. Keys `Gin˛` is not needed, you can write desired image width in `\includegraphics` options. But in case, when width of all image is the same (as can be understand from your question) with its use, the code is quite shorter.

Comment: I apologize, some images are too small using the same width for all columns, which I did not anticipate. When I change the width of each column, each image becomes very small. I updated my question with an example to demonstrate this.