# Timeline improve look to get a better understanding

Tags: tikz-arrows

[image: time line]

My timeline shows all the needed information. I now want to make it look nicer, but I don't know how. I thought about colors for each "type" and a better font, e.g. `\textnormal{}`.

What would you recommend? Can you help me out?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm, x=1cm, thick, font=\footnotesize]    
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
   brace_top/.style={
     decoration={brace},
     decorate
   },
   brace_bottom/.style={
     decoration={brace, mirror},
     decorate
   }
}

% time line week
\draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,0) -- coordinate (x axis) (8,0) node[right] {Days}; 
\foreach \x in {0,...,7} \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node[below] {\x};

% top brace
\node (start_week) at (0,0.1) {};
\node (end_week) at (7,0.1) {};
\draw [brace_top] (start_week.north) -- node [above, pos=0.5] {$|T| =a~Week = 672~Periods$} (end_week.north);

% low brace
\node (start_day_u) at (3,-0.4) {};
\node (end_day_u) at (4,-0.4) {};
\draw [brace_bottom] (start_day_u.south) -- node [below, pos=0.5] {} (end_day_u.south);

% time line day
\draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,-1.5) -- coordinate (x axis) (8,-1.5) node[right] {Hours}; 
\draw (0,-1.4) -- (0,-1.6) node[below] {1};
\foreach \x in {4,8,12,16,20,24} \draw (\x/3.4,-1.4) -- (\x/3.4,-1.6) node[below] {\x};
\draw (9/3.4,-1.4) -- (9/3.4,-1.6) node[below] {9};

% top brace
\node (start_day) at (0,-1.4) {};
\node (end_day) at (7,-1.4) {};
\draw [brace_top] (start_day.north) -- node [above, pos=0.5] {$ a~Day = 96~Periods$} (end_day.north);

% low brace
\node (start_hour_u) at (8/3.4,-1.9) {};
\node (end_hour_u) at (9/3.4,-1.9) {};
\draw [brace_bottom] (start_hour_u.south) -- node [below, pos=0.5] {} (end_hour_u.south);

% time line hour
\draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,-3.0) -- coordinate (x axis) (8,-3.0) node[right] {Minutes}; 
\draw (0,-2.9) -- (0,-3.1) node[below] {1};
\foreach \x in {15,30,45,60} \draw (\x/8.5,-2.9) -- (\x/8.5,-3.1) node[below] {\x};

% top brace
\node (start_hour) at (0,-2.9) {};
\node (end_hour) at (7.05,-2.9) {};
\draw [brace_top] (start_hour.north) -- node [above, pos=0.5] {$ a~Hour = 4~Periods$} (end_hour.north);

% time line period
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} \draw[dotted] (15*\x/8.5,-3.45) -- (15*\x/8.5,-3.6) node[below] {\textbf{\x}};

% low brace period
\node (start_period) at (30/8.5,-3.9) {};
\node (end_period) at (45/8.5,-3.9) {};
\draw [brace_bottom] (start_period.south) -- node [below, pos=0.5] {$t=a~Period$} (end_period.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The timeline is based on the following two examples:

- [Braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/how-to-join-underbrace-overbrace-between-nodes)
- [Coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97887/tikz-curly-braces-end-at-the-same-node-but-there-is-a-gap)

Thanks leaving all this great advices!

Comment: Ok then.  I shall delete prior comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. Use `siunitx` for typesetting units
2. Use colors to show the matching braces
3. Shift the number lines so that the corresponding braces are below each other.
4. Use `densely dotted` for the dots and apply a `y shift` so that they look more uniform.
5. Add `densely dotted` lines between the corresponding parts.
6. Horizontally extend the small braces slightly to the left and right, and also up vertically so that they are closer to the axis labels.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\DeclareSIUnit\periods{periods}
\DeclareSIUnit\weeks{week}
\DeclareSIUnit\days{days}
\DeclareSIUnit\hours{hours}
\DeclareSIUnit\minutes{minutes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm, x=1cm, thick, font=\footnotesize]    
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{number line/.style={}}

\tikzset{
   brace_top/.style={
     color=blue,
     decoration={brace},
     decorate
   },
   brace_bottom/.style={
     color=blue,
     decoration={brace, mirror},
     decorate
   }
}

\begin{scope}[xshift=0.9cm]
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-0.27cm]
        % time line week
        \draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,0) -- coordinate (x axis) (8,0) 
            node[right] {\si{\days}}; 
        \foreach \x in {0,...,7} \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node[below] {\x};
        
        % top brace
        \node (start_week) at (0,0.1) {};
        \node (end_week) at (7,0.1) {};
        \draw [brace_top] (start_week.north) -- node [above, pos=0.5] {$|T| = \SI[parse-numbers=false]{a}{\weeks} = \SI{672}{\periods}$} (end_week.north);
        
        % low brace
        \node (start_day_u) at (3,-0.4) {};
        \node (end_day_u) at (4,-0.4) {};
        \draw [brace_bottom, red] 
            ($(start_day_u.south)+(-0.3em,0.5ex)$) -- node [below, pos=0.5] {} ($(end_day_u.south)+(0.3em,0.5ex)$);
        \draw[densely dotted, red] 
            ($(start_day_u.south)!0.5!(end_day_u.south) +(0,-0.7ex)$) -- ++(0,-0.3);
    \end{scope}

    % time line day
    \draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,-1.5) -- coordinate (x axis) (8,-1.5) node[right] {\si{\hours}}; 
    \draw (0,-1.4) -- (0,-1.6) node[below] {1};
    \foreach \x in {4,8,12,16,20,24} \draw (\x/3.4,-1.4) -- (\x/3.4,-1.6) node[below] {\x};
    \draw (9/3.4,-1.4) -- (9/3.4,-1.6) node[below] {9};
    
    % top brace
    \node (start_day) at (0,-1.4) {};
    \node (end_day) at (7,-1.4) {};
    \draw [brace_top, red] (start_day.north) -- node [above, pos=0.5] {$ \SI[parse-numbers=false]{a}{\days} = \SI{96}{\periods}$} (end_day.north);
    
    % low brace
    \node (start_hour_u) at (8/3.4,-1.9) {};
    \node (end_hour_u) at (9/3.4,-1.9) {};
    \draw [brace_bottom, brown] ($(start_hour_u.south)+(-0.3em,0.5ex)$) -- node [below, pos=0.5] {} ($(end_hour_u.south)+(0.3em,0.5ex)$);
        \draw[densely dotted, brown] 
            ($(start_hour_u.south)!0.5!(end_hour_u.south) +(0,-0.7ex)$) -- ++(0,-0.3);
\end{scope}

% time line hour
\draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,-3.0) -- coordinate (x axis) (8,-3.0) node[right] {\si{\minutes}}; 
\draw (0,-2.9) -- (0,-3.1) node[below] {1};
\foreach \x in {15,30,45,60} \draw (\x/8.5,-2.9) -- (\x/8.5,-3.1) node[below] {\x};

% top brace
\node (start_hour) at (0,-2.9) {};
\node (end_hour) at (7.05,-2.9) {};
\draw [brace_top, brown] (start_hour.north) -- node [above, pos=0.5] {$ \SI[parse-numbers=false]{a}{\hours} = \SI{4}{\periods}$} (end_hour.north);

% time line period
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} \draw[densely dotted, yshift=-0.5ex] (15*\x/8.5,-3.45) -- (15*\x/8.5,-3.6) 
    node[below] {\textbf{\x}};

% low brace period
\node (start_period) at (30/8.5,-3.9) {};
\node (end_period) at (45/8.5,-3.9) {};
\draw [brace_bottom] ($(start_period.south)+(-0.3em,0)$) -- node [below, pos=0.5] {$t=\SI[parse-numbers=false]{a}{\periods}$} ($(end_period.south)+(0.3em,0)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are `periods`, `week`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes` really units?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I think that they are as they.

Comment: They are somehow :) Really, really nice! Thanks. Last but not least can I do something about the "s" at the end of some units?

Comment: Perhaps changing the definition in `\DeclareSIUnit`? Not sure exactly what you desire so am leaving it for you.

Comment: @PeterGrill I tried changing the definition. The problem is a single "day" shouldn't have an "s" where if it is plural it needs "days". Can I adjust this? The [doc](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) is quite extensive.

Comment: That would be a good separate question on `siunitx`. But usually units are abbreviated to `d`, `h` etc so not normally an issue.

Comment: Why do minutes and hours start at 1 whereas days start at 0?

Comment: @cfr: Good question. I assume I just adapted the code form the question as that is exactly what the OP shows in the figure.

Comment: A question for @lony then :-).