# How can I draw event on top of each other on a timeline?

Tags: tikz-pgf, timeline, tikz-timing

I want to draw events on top of each other on a time-line. As an example, I want to draw following figure, where event boxes could be place in different locations:

[image]

---

For https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436306/127048 I was able to come up with:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ImageWidth}{11cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % draw horizontal line
    \draw[thick, -Triangle] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[font=\scriptsize,below left=3pt and -8pt]{hours};

    % draw vertical lines
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
    \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);

    \foreach \x/\descr in {0/t_{1},1/t_{2},2/t_{3},3/t_{4}}
    \node[font=\scriptsize, text height=1.75ex,
    text depth=.5ex] at (\x,-.3) {$\descr$};

    % colored bar up
    \foreach \x/\perccol in
    {0/100,1/75}
    \draw[lightgray!\perccol!lightgray, line width=4pt]
    (\x,.5) -- +(1,0);

    % colored bar down
    \foreach \x/\perccol in
    {3/100,4/75,5/0}
    (\x,-.7) -- +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210370/127048

Comment: Have you considered using the `pgfgantt` package?

Comment: That was in my mind, do you think its easier with `pgfgantt`? Also I had to combine pgfgantt along with other tikz figures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ImageWidth}{11cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % draw horizontal line
        \draw[thick, -Triangle] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[font=\scriptsize,below left=3pt and -8pt]{hours};
        
        % draw vertical lines
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
        \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);
        
        \foreach \x/\descr in {0/t_{1},1/t_{2},2/t_{3},3/t_{4}}
        \node[font=\scriptsize, text height=1.75ex,
        text depth=.5ex] at (\x,-.3) {$\descr$};
        
        % colored bar1 up   
        \draw[lightgray!50!lightgray, line width=7pt]
        (0,.5) -- +(2,0)  node[pos=.5,white] () {one};
        
        % colored bar2 up
        \draw[lightgray!50!red, line width=7pt]
        (0,.8) -- +(2,0)  node[pos=.5,white] () {two};
        
        % colored bar2 down
        \draw[lightgray!50!green, line width=7pt]
        (2,-.6) -- +(1.5,0)  node[pos=.5,white] () {three};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE FOR DASHED LINES**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ImageWidth}{11cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % draw horizontal line
        \draw[thick, -Triangle] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[font=\scriptsize,below left=3pt and -8pt]{hours};
        
        % draw vertical lines
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
        \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);
        
        \foreach \x/\descr in {0/t_{1},1/t_{2},2/t_{3},3/t_{4}}
        \node[font=\scriptsize, text height=1.75ex,
        text depth=.5ex] at (\x,-.3) {$\descr$};
        
        % colored bar1 up   
        \draw[lightgray!50!lightgray, line width=7pt]
        (0,.5) -- +(2,0)  node[pos=.5,white] () {one};
        
        % colored bar2 up
        \draw[lightgray!50!red, line width=7pt]
        (0,.8) -- +(2,0)  node[pos=.5,white] () {two};
        
        % colored bar2 down
        \draw[lightgray!50!green, line width=7pt]
        (2,-.6) -- +(1.5,0)  node[pos=.5,white] () {three};
        
        % dotted lines
        \foreach \x in {0,2}
            \draw[dashed] (\x,0)--(\x,1);
        \foreach \x in {2,3.5}
            \draw[dashed] (\x,0)--(\x,-.7);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Final update**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ImageWidth}{11cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % grid
        \draw[gray!20,step=.25] (-1,-1) grid (6,2); 
        % draw horizontal line
        \draw[thick, -Triangle] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[font=\scriptsize,below left=3pt and -8pt]{hours};
        
        % draw vertical lines
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
        \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);
        
        \foreach \x/\descr in {0/t_{1},1/t_{2},2/t_{3},3/t_{4}}
        \node[font=\scriptsize, text height=1.75ex,
        text depth=.5ex] at (\x,-.3) {$\descr$};
        
        % colored bar1 up   
        \draw[lightgray!50!lightgray, line width=7pt]
        (0,.5) -- +(2,0)  node[pos=.5,white] () {one};
        
        % colored bar2 up
        \draw[lightgray!50!red, line width=7pt]
        (0,.8) -- +(2,0)  node[pos=.5,white] () {two};
        
        % colored bar2 down
        \draw[lightgray!50!green, line width=7pt]
        (2,-.6) -- +(1.5,0)  node[pos=.5,white] () {three};
        
        % dotted lines
        \foreach \x in {0,2}
            \draw[dashed] (\x,0)--(\x,1);
        \foreach \x in {2,3.5}
            \draw[dashed] (\x,0)--(\x,-.7);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add light-gray grid lines at the background like `pgfgantt` has? Sorry I tried to add the dashed lines in my figure but it wasn't that clear

Comment: @alper If You want also a bg lightgray grid add ths code insede the pkzpicture environnement:
  \draw[gray!20] (-1,-1) grid (6,2);

Comment: Is it also possible to add borders for the ractangle?

Comment: Now You dont have rectangle, but some large lines widhts. Perhaps You need to restart with rectangles...

Comment: Large lines are better :-)

Comment: I agree. I think it is enalph for now.

Comment: Final Q, can we make the grid more rapid (smaller boxes)? if possible I want to have additinoal lightgray line for all in between t_{n},t_{n+1} as well