# Tabular with overbrackets connecting elements

Tags: tables, tikz-trees, brackets, braces, overbrace

I want to make a vertical tree with brackets like the one bellow.

[image]

I tried `\overbrace` but I can't connect the 2nd row nodes (`\Omega_{r}` and `\Omega_{m}`) with the first.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|c c c}
Total matter&& $\Omega$ &\\
Different equations of state &$\Omega_{m}$&$\Omega_{r}$&$\Omega_{\Lambda}$\\
Difefrent species &$\overbrace{\Omega_{b}\quad\Omega_{c}}^{}$&
 $\overbrace{\Omega_{\gamma}\quad\Omega_{\nu}}^{}$&
\end{tabular}
```

I get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution playing with `\raisebox` (by trial ans errors!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|c c c}
Total matter & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\enspace\raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt][2.6ex]{$ \overbrace{\vphantom{-}\hspace{9.5em}}^{\textstyle \Omega}$}}\\
Different equations of state & $\Omega_{m}$&$\Omega_{r}$&$\Omega_{\Lambda}$\\
Different species &$\overbrace{\Omega_{b}\quad\Omega_{c}}^{}$&
 $\overbrace{\Omega_{\gamma}\quad\Omega_{\nu}}^{}$&
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite certain if this is feasible via `\overbrace`. I think `\overbrace` can only span things contained within the same math environment (at least I have not found any information indicating otherwise; but I have admittedly not had any personal experience with this particular command).

I have tried out an alternative approach, usint `TikZ` trees. The result looks as follows:
[image: code result]

The code:

```
    \documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level distance=10mm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
    ]
    % The main tree
    \node (omega) {$\Omega$} [draw=white]
        child {
            node (w_m) {$\Omega_{m}$}
            child {node (w_b) {$\Omega_{b}$}}
            child {node (w_c) {$\Omega_{c}$}}
        }
        child {
            node (w_r) {$\Omega_{r}$}
            child {node (w_gamma) {$\Omega_{\gamma}$}}
            child {node (w_nu)    {$\Omega_{\nu}$}}
        }
        child {node (w_lambda) {$\Omega_{\Lambda}$}}
    ;

    \begin{scope}[
        every path/.append style={
            decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2mm}}
        ]
        \draw (w_m.north west)     -- (w_lambda.north east);
        \draw (w_b.north west)     -- (w_c.north east);
        \draw (w_gamma.north west) -- (w_nu.north east);
    \end{scope}

    % Text on left  side is put in a tree  as well, thus
    % ensuring that the vertical spacing is identical to
    % the actual tree.
    \begin{scope}[
        every node/.append style={
            text width=50mm,
            align=left,
            draw=none
            },
            every child/.append style={draw=white},
        ]
        \node[left=50mm of omega] (tot_matter) {Total Matter}
            child {
                node (d_eqs) {Different equations of state}
                child {node (d_species) {Different species}}
            }
            ;
    \end{scope}

    % Vertical separator line
    \draw (tot_matter.north east) -- (d_species.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The placement in this example was done by hand, which is of course a bit crude, and could use some further optimization, but you get the idea.

Jake goes into a bit more detail on the `brace` decoration for `TikZ` in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34450/131649

You can also find more information on it in the PGF manual in Section 21 -- *Making Trees Grow*, on p.316ff:
http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Of course, if there is an nice way to just do this via a tabular and some nicely-scaling braces, that would probably be easier. The nice thing about using `TikZ` for drawing trees is that they scale very easily. But not every situation needs that, admittedly.

Oh, and welcome to TeX.sx!

Answer (score 3):

If it is a tree, it *could* be a Forest ....

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
    fit=band,
    edge path'={
      (.parent first) -- (!ul.parent last)
    },
    edge+={decorate, decoration={brace}},
    l sep'=0pt,
  },
  for n=1{
    tikz+={
      \node (n) [fit to=tree] {};
      \draw (n.north east) -- (n.south east);
    },
  },
  for nodewalk={
    1,
    descendants
  }{no edge, plain content, anchor=mid west},
  for nodewalk={2,descendants}{
    before typesetting nodes={
      if content={}{
        content=\Omega
      }{
        content/.wrap value=\Omega_{#1},
        before packing={
          text width/.process={OOPw3{max x}{min x}{width("$\Omega$")}{#3+.25*(#1-#2)}},
          text centered,
          typeset node,
        },
      },
      anchor=mid,
      if n=1{}{no edge},
    },
  },
  [, phantom
    [Total matter
      [Different equations of state
        [Different species]
      ]
    ]
    [
      [m
        [b]
        [c]
      ]
      [r
        [\gamma]
        [\nu]
      ]
      [\Lambda]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: bracket edges]

Answer (score 2):

With TABstacks (no trial and error `\raisebox`ing)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\TABstackMath% PROCESS TABstacks IN MATH MODE (REGULAR STACKS IN TEXT MODE)
%\fixTABwidth{T}% MAKE TABstack COLUMNS EQUAL WIDTH
\setstacktabbedgap{\tabcolsep}% GAP BETWEEN COLUMNS
\setstackgap{L}{1.8\normalbaselineskip}% BASELINESKIP BETWEEN ROWS
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}% DEFAULT TO "LONG" STACKS
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\Longunderstack[l]{Total matter\\Different equations of state\\Different species}
&
\stackunder{$\Omega$}{$\overbrace{\tabbedLongunderstack{
  \Omega_m & \Omega_r & \Omega_\Lambda\\
  \overbrace{\Omega_b\quad\Omega_c}&
  \overbrace{\Omega_\gamma\quad\Omega_\nu}&
}}$}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I uncomment the one line in the preamble, to force all column widths equal,

[image]