# Question about aligning line segments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have written this code for two line segments. I want to line them up to show that you can take sub intervals of the original, and add it to the new line segment.

```
\begin{center}
    {$\overline{\rm AB}$}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
{$\overline{\rm CD}$}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (7.5,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
```

I'd love something like this:

[image: Line Segment Comparison]

Comment: Do you really need tikz to do that?

Comment: I'm very new to latex, would you know something better that could do that?

Comment: If you want something more like underbraces, have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/how-to-join-underbrace-overbrace-between-nodes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with simple `\rule` commands and the `mathtools` package. I took the liberty to replace the `\underbrace`s with `\underbracket`s, as I find them more expressive in this context:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \begin{gathered}
           \overline{\mathrm{AB}} \\[-2.5ex]
           \underbracket[0.5pt]{\rule{2cm}{0.8pt}}_{\tfrac{1}{2}} \clap{\rule{0.4em}{0.8pt}}\mkern-3mu \underbracket[0.5pt]{\rule{2cm}{0.8pt}}_{\tfrac{1}{2}}
        \end{gathered}
        & \qquad
   \begin{gathered}
           \overline{\mathrm{CD}} \\[-2.5ex]
           \underbracket[0.5pt]{\rule{2cm}{0.8pt}}_{\tfrac{1}{2}} \clap{\rule{0.4em}{0.8pt}} \mkern-3mu \underbracket[0.5pt]{\rule{2cm}{0.8pt}}_{\tfrac{1}{2}} \clap{\rule{0.4em}{0.8pt}} \mkern-3mu \underbracket[0.5pt]{\rule{2cm}{0.8pt}}_{\tfrac{1}{2}}
        \end{gathered}
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I love you so much bro thank you <3

Comment: Note you can use as a second optional argument of `\underbracket` the length of its vertical part.